# Which Naruto episode shows Hidan attacking Naruto?

Tags: naruto

Does anyone know that *Naruto* episode when Hidan attacks Naruto and Naruto goes down because he doesn't have enough time to react? Sasuke and Sakura were both with him at the time.

Comment: the Akatsuki start turning up **after Sasuke has left the village to join Orochimaru** as such it's not possible for Naruto to encounter Hidan and have Sasuke and Sakura with him. the only Akatsuki to turn up before then was Itachi and the shark dude

Comment: @Memor-X Well, I remember it happening! ^~^

Answer (score 4):

In the original Naruto series, the only Akatsuki members that are shown are Itachi and Kisame. [Hidan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hidan) isn’t shown until later until the Shippūden series, and, as a matter of fact, Hidan and Naruto have actually *never* encountered each other except for in the Infinite Tsukuyomi

> Hidan is the only member of Nagato's Akatsuki to have never met Naruto Uzumaki. However, in the anime of Tsunade's Infinite Tsukuyomi dream, Naruto encounters Hidan.

The filler episode for Tsunade's Infinite Tsukuyomi is [Shippūden episode 433](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/The_Search_Mission), which does take place in the time frame of when Team 7 are kids.

Comment: Do you know what episode that was? Maybe I’m just misremembering, sorry!

Comment: @user35581 edited my question with the episode number

Comment: Glad I could help!